# Convert Integer field Date time to Date Time

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, unix-timestamp

I am working in SQL Server 2012. My datetime column in a data set looks like this: `1512543210`. The column is in int. I want to convert it to something like `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss` e.g. `01-01-2019 12:12:12`. But I can not do this. I am using following code:

```
select dateadd(SS, 1512543210, '01/01/1970 00:00:00') as datetime
from sampledb
```

after execute query i got this.

```
2017-12-06 00:00:00.0
```

but i want this format;

```
06-12-2017 00:00:00
```

Comment: Date and time datatypes don't have a "format", they are stored as a binary value. if the format of the date is important, then you need to address that in your presentation layer, not the SQL.

Comment: and why is this tagged Java?

Comment: Wrap the `dateadd(...)` inside `FORMAT(..., 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')`. BTW the date seems like Dec 6 2017.

Comment: Carlos Heuberger, i am using java for developing

Comment: Salman A i tried this but not Working

Comment: `FORMAT` is great as a performance killer @SalmanA,  honestly it should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: If `format` doesn't work, perhaps you're running a [compatibility level](https://www.spiria.com/en/blog/web-applications/understanding-sql-server-compatibility-levels/) older than 2012?

Comment: Not to mention that using FORMAT turns a datetime into a string so things like sorting in the front end have been killed. Send a datetime to the presentation layer so things work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DATEADD` to convert UNIX timestamp to `DATETIME` and `FORMAT` function to [format it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings):

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(SECOND, 1512543210, '19700101'), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss')
-- 06-12-2017 06:53:30
```

Having said that, Java has DateTimeFormatter class for formatting dates. And timestamps could be used to construct date objects directly.

Comment: The question is for SQL Server 2012, but `format` was added in SQL Server 2017

Comment: Hard to find on MSDN, but [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_format.asp) agrees, +1

Comment: The *"in SQL Server 2017"* on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014) is incredibly misleading but it most definitely was added on 2012 @Andomar . I'll raise change request on the github.

Comment: @SalmanA i have one doubt also to convert 06-12-2017 to '1512543210' this format

Comment: `SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, '19700101', '20171206')`

Comment: @SalmanA i am grateful to you for your help. the code given me is working prefectly

Comment: @SalmanA i have a time field in integer format like 571. the actual time is 09:31. i use FORMAT to convert this field to time. but the result is 00:00:000. Please help me to convert this field to actual time format.    FORMAT(DATEADD(SECOND, nStartTime, '19700101'), 'hh:mm')as FirstInTime

Comment: If 571 is 9:31 then it is the number of minutes, not seconds: `SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(MINUTE, 571, 0), 'hh:mm') -- 09:31`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CONVERT option

```
select CONVERT(varchar,dateadd(SS,DateTime,'01/01/1970 00:00:00') ,21) as datetime from sampledb
```

Comment: when i run this query, i got this output 2017-12-06 00:00:00.0. the time will not read in this query.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it in the database query as stated in comments and at least one other answer, but you can do it in Java, too:

Have a look at this example:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // take the moment represented by the int from the database
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1512543210);
    // create a datetime object (modern java api)
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    // create a formatter for the pattern of your choice
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    // then print the datetime using the desired format
    System.out.println(ldt.format(dtf));
}
```

This outputs

```
06-12-2017 07:53:30
```

in my IDE, please check that code in yours.

> Please note that you don't need to do the `DATEADD` operation in SQL for this, just fetch the `int` value from the database by something like `resultSet.getInt(...)` and pass it to the `Instant.ofEpochSeconds(...)`, it will calculate the time based on `"1970-01-01 00:00:00"`.

Comment: What makes you think Java is an appropriate solution?

Comment: @Andomar The question was tagged `java`... Well, that is obviously not the case anymore, but this provides an alternative.

Comment: Aha right, the history shows the Java tag was edited out

Comment: @deHaar the output of the value is wrong. actual output is 06-12-2017 06:53:30.

Comment: @AbdulRashidA Possibly a time zone thing, you can use `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` instead and set a zone or an offset to make the time correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
select FORMAT(dateadd(SS,1512543210,'01/01/1970 00:00:00'), N'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on an older version of SQL Server, the `format` function is not available. An alternative is [`convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with style `105` (Italian) to get the `MM-dd-yyyy` part.  Then you can take the last part of the `120` (odbc canonical) style to get the `hh:mm:ss` part:

```
select convert(varchar(30), dateadd(second, 1512543210, '1970-01-01'), 105) + ' ' + 
       substring(convert(varchar(30), dateadd(second, 1512543210, '1970-01-01'), 20), 12, 8)
-->
06-12-2017 06:53:30
```

[Example at rextester.](https://rextester.com/WQPE25015)

Comment: when i use this query with field name. i got a mistake that the date is correctly but time is same on all rows

Comment: Did you replace both instances of 1512543210?